# Converting a php array to XML Soap api

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am have trouble converting array to xml here as the CustomerOrderLines are getting repeated, the xml generated gets only the last [CustomerOrderLines] value, how do i generate an xml with all the objects.

```
public function ProcessOrderAction(){
$subTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
$quoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId(); 
$quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")->load($quoteId); 
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer(); 
$customerAddress = array();
$_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()-    >addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerData->getId());                        
$_orderCnt = $_orders->count(); //orders count
if($_orderCnt == 0){
$CustomerOperation="Create";    
}else{
$CustomerOperation="Find";  
}
$soapClient = new    SoapClient("https://api.ongoingsystems.se/Colliflow/service.asmx?wsdl",  array('trace' => 1)); 
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$store = Mage::app('checkout/session')->getStore();
$ap_param = array(
'GoodsOwnerCode'=>'Test',
'UserName'      =>    'test', 
'Password'      =>    'test',
'co'=> [
'OrderInfo'=>[
'OrderIdentification' => 'SystemId',
'OrderOperation' => 'Create',
'GoodsOwnerOrderNumber' => '1111',
'OrderId' => '',
'GoodsOwnerOrderId' => '102',
'DeliveryDate' => '2016-05-14T22:16:00',
'OrderType'=> [
'OrderTypeOperation' => 'CreateOrFind',
'OrderTypeIdentification' => 'OrderTypeCode'
]
],

'Customer'=> [
'CustomerOperation' => $CustomerOperation,
'CustomerIdentification' => 'CustomerNumber',
'ExternalCustomerCode' => 'ExternalCustomerCode',
'CustomerNumber' => ''.$customerData->getId(),
'CustomerId' => ''.$customerData->getId(),
'Name' => ''.$customerData->getName(),
'Address' => ''.$customerAddress['region'],
'PostCode' => ''.$customerAddress['postcode'],
'City' => ''.$customerAddress['city'],
'TelePhone' => ''.$customerAddress['telephone'],
'Remark' => 'Remarks',
'IsVisible'=>'true',
'NotifyBySMS'=> 'true',
'NotifyByEmail'=> 'false',
'NotifyByTelephone'=>'false',
'Email' => ''.$customerData->getEmail(),
'MobilePhone' => ''.$customerAddress['telephone'],
'CountryCode' =>'NO',
'CountryStateCode' => '90'
],
'CustomerOrderLines' => [
'CustomerOrderLine'=> [
'OrderLineIdentification' => 'ArticleNumber',
'ArticleIdentification' => 'ArticleNumber',
'OrderLineSystemId' => '123',
'ExternalOrderLineCode' => 'ExternalOrderLineId',
'ArticleSystemId' => '123',
'ArticleNumber' => ''.$item->getSku(),
'ArticleName' => ''.$item->getName(),
'NumberOfItems' => '6',
'ProductCode' => ''.$item->getProductId()
],
'CustomerOrderLine'=> [
'OrderLineIdentification' => 'ArticleNumber',
'ArticleIdentification' => 'ArticleNumber',
'OrderLineSystemId' => '1231',
'ExternalOrderLineCode' => 'ExternalOrderLineId',
'ArticleSystemId' => '1230',
'ArticleNumber' => '0000099',
'ArticleName' => 'test222',
'NumberOfItems' => '6',
'ProductCode' => '6786978'
]
]
]
);
print_r($ap_param);
$error = 0; 
try { 
$info = $soapClient->__call("ProcessOrder", array($ap_param)); 
}catch (SoapFault $fault) { 
$error = 1; 
print(" 
alert('Sorry, returned the following ERROR: ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring.". We will now take you back to our home page.'); 
            window.location = 'main.php'; ");   
}
if ($error == 0) {        
$auth_num = $info->ProcessOrderResult; 
print_r($auth_num);
}
}
```

Comment: create xml node using object $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0"); and add nodes using the loop , add attributes for each value to each node... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml might help

Comment: *the xml generated gets only the last [CustomerOrderLines] value*...not a SOAP expert but where is the xml generated in the code? I am not seeing DOM, SimpleXML, or other XML objects.

Comment: Do your arrays match the data structures found in the wsdl?  If yes, then PHP will convert your arrays to XML automatically.  To see what it generated, do $soapClient->__getLastRequest()